# MYSQL: To kill process using sys_exec()

Tags: mysql, shell

Question: How to kill process using sys_exec().
I am trying to execute shell script using the sys_exec().
my shell script contains

```
killall process_name
```

when i execute above script, at that time it is not calling

`killall process_name`

command. But it executes other operations like `

sys_exec(touch filename.txt);`

How to execute above shellscript?

Comment: may be this can help .. http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.in/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html

Comment: Yes amit I already tried that...but when i am trying to kill any process using mysql at that time it's not kill process..so may be  mysql has no permission to kill the process..so how can i change that permission any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `MySQL 5.1` where the processlist is in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, you can do this to generate the `KILL QUERY` commands in bulk from within the mysql client:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('KILL QUERY ',id,';') SEPARATOR ' ') KillQuery
FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user<>'system user'\G
```

You might want to take a look at these links

**http://dbadiaries.com/how-to-kill-all-mysql-processes-for-a-specific-user
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2634/kill-all-queries-mysql**

Comment: when i execute  SELECT sys_exec('touch /tmp/test.txt'); this from mysql  then its work for me...but...when i execute  SELECT sys_exec('sh /home/ketul/sig.sh'); its not work for me...sig.sh contains 'kill processname'